# QtCreator std::cout and output pane

Tags: c++, qt-creator

When I run console applications in QtCreator the output (and input - std::cout, std::cin) is done via xterm (my OS is debian). How can I make output to be shown in the QtCreator's output pane not in the xterm window?

Answer (score 1):

From the Qt Creator website:

> Application Output
>
> The Application Output pane displays the status of a program when it is executed, and the debug output.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html

It does not look like the Application Output window is what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the QDebug() function for this. It's usage is pretty much the same as std::cout.
Look at the example below:

```
float coordinate = 3.41;
qDebug() << "Custom coordinate type:" << coordinate;
```

This will output, in your QtCreator's output pane:

> Custom coordinate type: 3.41

Don't forget to include this statement, in your includes block:

`#include <QDebug>`

For more information, check this link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html